# Como Definir as Rotas de Recurso (resource) no LARAVEL 8

Tags: laravel, controller, resources, vue-router

Não estou conseguindo referenciar um controlador de CRUD no laravel 8, apesar de ja ter procurado no site oficial do Laravel e testado os codigos la mostrados,  não consegui evoluir.

O que eu fiz:

1 - já criei o Controle através do shell do windows:

```
php artisan make:controller Admin/ArtigosController --resource
```

2 - Em seguida Vou na pasta de routes/web.php e crio as seguintes Rotas adicionais: (a HOME já vem com o Laravel, não mexo nela):

```
Route::middleware(['auth']) -> prefix('admin') -> namespace('Admin') -> group(function(){

Route::resource ('artigos',ArtigosController::class); // aqui está exatamente como no site versão Laravel 8.
});
```

3 - Em seguida eu deveria digitar o seguinte endereço no navegador: http://localhost:8000/admin/artigos e retornar a mensagem de "ok" (método esse que está na função index do Controller que eu criei), mas em vez disso, aparece a mensagem abaixo. Conforme podem ver ele não esta reconhecendo o meu Controller.:

[image: TELA DE ERRO NÃO RECONHECEDO MEU CONTROLLER]

.......

Ja tentei colocar também como sugerido por um moderador daqui o código abaixo no arquivo routes/web.php e também não funcionou:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArtigosController;
```

Já tentei chamar o Controller inclusive como:

```
Route::resource ('artigos',action: 'ArtigosController@index')
```

Se puderem me ajudar agradeço muito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Laravel 8 em diante você precisa importar a classe ou usar seu nome completo nas declarações de rota. Elas não são mais importadas automaticamente.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArtigosController;

Route::resource ('artigos', ArtigosController::class);
```

Ou, usando o caminho completo:

```
Route::resource ('artigos', App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArtigosController::class);
```

Comment: Grande #cypherpotato Obrigado pela dica funcionou com a primeira opção mesmo. Muito obrigado!! Mas eu tive que retirar o namespace Admin pois , se não ele ia retornar como se fosse a primeira pasta assim: Admin\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArtigosController::class);

Comment: @FabricioGuimaraes você pode manter a instrução de namespace se especificar que o App está na raiz com `\App` ao invés de somente `App`

Comment: Poxa melhor ainda cara, Ajudou muito..... Muito obrigado pela dica. Sucesso